# Custom shape with rounded corners in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have created custom shape and I want to round it's corners a bit.

Below I present my code along with pictures of what I currently have, and what I want to achieve.

```
class CustomShape : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline {
        val path = androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Path().apply {
            lineTo(0f, size.height)
            lineTo(size.width, size.height)
            lineTo(size.width, (size.height / 2.5).toFloat())
            close()

        }
        return Outline.Generic(path)
    }
}
```

I'm applying it in the Box:

```
 Box(modifier = Modifier
                .widthIn(min = 250.dp, max = 250.dp)){
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .widthIn(min = 250.dp, max = 250.dp)
                    .height(150.dp)
                     .clip(CustomShape())
                    .background(
                        brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                            colors = listOf(Color(0xFF5936B4), Color(0xFF362A84))
                        )
                    ).align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
            ) {}
            Content()
        }
```

The actual effect looks like this:

[image]

What I want to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use canvas and draw outline with `PathEffect.cornerPathEffect(60f)`. Here radius is 60F you can use customize this to your needs.

```
@Composable
fun ShapeTry() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 100.dp)
            .widthIn(min = 250.dp, max = 250.dp)
    ) {
       val list =  listOf(Color(0xFF5936B4), Color(0xFF362A84))
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(250.dp)
                .height(150.dp)
        ) {
            val rect = Rect(Offset.Zero, size)

            val path = androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Path().apply {
                lineTo(0f, size.height)
                lineTo(size.width, size.height)
                lineTo(size.width, (size.height / 2.5).toFloat())
                close()

            }

           val paint =  Paint().apply {
               shader = LinearGradientShader(
                   rect.topLeft,
                   rect.bottomRight,
                   list
               )
               pathEffect = PathEffect.cornerPathEffect(60f)
           }
            drawIntoCanvas { canvas ->
                canvas.drawOutline(
                    outline = Outline.Generic(path),
                    paint = paint
                )
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add another clip

```
   .clip(RoundedCornerShape(15.dp))
```